# How do i map multiple left outer joins to inherited objects with dapper?

Tags: .net, oop, dapper

I'm using Dapper and I am trying to produce a list with 3 classes, 2 inherited and a base class . These classes are:

```
public class Cow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Steak: Cow
{
    public int DonenessId { get; set; }
}
public class Jerky: Cow
{
    public int MarinadeId { get; set; }
}
```

My stored procedure doesn't have any parameters and uses left outer joins:

```
SELECT *  FROM Cow c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Jerky j ON j.CowId = c.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Steak s ON s.CowId = c.Id
```

=

```
+----+----------+------+-------+------------+------+-------+------------+
| Id | Name     | Id   | CowId | MarinadeId | Id   | CowId | DonenessId |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Artricia | NULL | NULL  | NULL       | 21   |   1   | 5          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | Betty    | 13   | 2     | 3          | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | Cindy    | 14   | 3     | 1          | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4  | Denile   | NULL | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 5  | Enid     | NULL | NULL  | NULL       | 22   | 5     | 3          |
+----+----------+------+-------+------------+------+-------+------------+
```

I'm trying to produce a list of Cow objects so I can loop through them, I need to use Dapper for my organisation and I need it in one stored procedure.

From the above results I'm looking to achieve a list of 5 Cow Objects where 2 can be casted as Steak and 2 can be casted as Jerky.

Edit: Refined what I'm asking for.

I'm stuck because I don't know what to put in the `map:` argument of the query. Additionally should the type be , or ?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem, instead of deleting the question I'll leave the answer here because it took alot of bashing and i worked hard on this beef abstraction for y'all.

Firstly, the result set of the stored procedure has to have better names for the columns.

```
SELECT 
c.Id AS Id, 
c.Name AS Name,
j.Id AS JerkyId,
j.MarinadeId AS JerkyMarinadeId,
s.Id AS SteakId,
s.DonenessId AS SteakDonenessId
FROM Cow c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Jerky j ON j.CowId = c.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Steak s ON s.CowId = c.Id
```

Since there are now uniquely named columns which seperate the joins, we can splitOn:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Cow>();
_dbConnection.Query<Cow, Jerky, Steak, Cow>(QueryConstants.MeatDetective,
    (c, j, s) =>
    {
        Cow cow;
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(c.Id, out cow))
        {
            if (s != null)
            {
                s.Id = c.Id;
                s.Name = c.Name;
                lookup.Add(c.Id, s);
            }
            else if (j != null)
            {
                j.Id = c.Id;
                j.Name = c.Name;
                lookup.Add(c.Id, j);
            }
            else
            {
                lookup.Add(c.Id, c);
            }
        }

        return cow;
    }, splitOn: "JerkyId,SteakId");
    var beef = lookup.Values.ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Cows  : " + beef.Count() + ".");
    Console.WriteLine("Steaks: " + beef.OfType<Steak>().Count() + ".");
    Console.WriteLine("Jerkys: " + beef.OfType<Jerky>().Count() + ".");
```

Produces:

```
Cows  : 5.
Steak : 2.
Jerky : 2.
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you wanted to use this map for joins where you'd need multiple objects from each row then change if(s)..elif..else to if...if...if.